# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection Network Error in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I setup my local server using `express.js`, That simply handle request and return simple message.

```
app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world !');
});
```

I executed server and test it on web-browser, it works well.

Simply I want to do that on my `react-native` app.

this is my `action.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios';

exports.helloButtonPressAct = (email, password) => {
    return function (dispatch) {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/hello')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                // and create action obj here
                // dispatch(someAction(...))
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                throw error;
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
};
```

It only return `catch()` result.

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Network Error  Error:
>   Network Error at createError ...

[image]

Maybe something wrong but I couldn't find what is it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved.

`return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/hello')`

to

`return axios.get('http://10.0.0.2:3000/hello')`

and It works.

In Android emulator, the `localhost` refers its device.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404